# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.16:test (default-test) on project mahout-math: There are test failures

Tags: maven, mahout, failed-installation

Trying to install Mahout on Ubuntu16.04, I have successfully install maven 3.3.9 and subversion 1.9.3. New to mahout and maven, I don't know if I should skip the test and just use

```
mvn -DskipTests
```

Here is the error I got:

```
[INFO] Mahout Build Tools ................................. SUCCESS [  6.621 s]
[INFO] Apache Mahout ...................................... SUCCESS [  1.164 s]
[INFO] Mahout Math ........................................ FAILURE [03:35 min]
[INFO] Mahout MapReduce Legacy ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Mahout Integration ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Mahout Examples .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Mahout Release Package ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Mahout Math/Scala wrappers ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Mahout Spark bindings .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Mahout Spark bindings shell ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 03:44 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-10-07T19:05:02-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 33M/134M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-
surefire-plugin:2.16:test (default-test) on project mahout-math: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to/home/flora/.linuxbrew/Cellar/mahout/trunk/math/target/surefire-reports 
for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.16:test (default-test) on project mahout-math: There are test failures.

Please refer to /home/flora/.linuxbrew/Cellar/mahout/trunk/math/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: There are test failures.

```
Please refer to /home/flora/.linuxbrew/Cellar/mahout/trunk/math/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefireHelper.reportExecution(SurefireHelper.java:82)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin.handleSummary(SurefirePlugin.java:190)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:852)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:720)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
... 20 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :mahout-math
```

Comment: The version of the checked out sources having test failures...You must decide if you like to use this...You can of course skip the failing tests by using `-DskipTests` ?

Answer (score 0):

I use Maven 3.3.9, but I can't just use "mvn -DskipTests", it will fail because of lacking lifecycle phase or a goal. Here is error message:

```
[ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
```

There are two methods to ignore unit tests' failures. Use phase install for example:

```
method 1: mvn -DskipTests install

method 2: mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true install
```

The difference between two methods is that the former will compile the unit tests and the latter won't, so the latter can skip compile failure, the former cannot.

[Maven Surefire Plugin: Skipping Tests](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/skipping-test.html)